i have installed ubuntu on my laptop yet i cant connect to the internet i have figured out it is a DNS configuration error how do i solve it
I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop bare Metal the latest version of 2024
if I try and access the internet from any browser I can't because of name resolution
if I ping an IP directly I get a connection
I have checked resolv.conf file, systemd-rsolved, and network manager and I can't find the issue
I have been at this for the whole day how do I fix this completely

Without output of resolvectl command we have no way to help you. Please provide these: systemctl status systemd-resolved; resolvectl; ls -l /etc/resolv.conf; dig example.com
